# how to convert the column names of a data frame to a column and remove those unwanted one?

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df <-  structure(list(dar.MN.L = c(0.6182, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02381, 
    0.070409, NaN, 0.092676, 0.21529, NaN, 0.072563), dar.MN.L.normalized = c(0.88095, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.034051, 0.079625, NaN, 0.1338, 0.28808, 
    NaN, 0.10199), dar.MN.L.variability.... = c(24.124, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 168.42, 225.67, NaN, 108.66, 113.49, NaN, 92.103), 
        dar.MN.L.count = c(26L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31L, 6L, 
        0L, 74L, 133L, 1L, 186L), dar.MN.L.iso.count = c(0L, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31L, 6L, 0L, 74L, 133L, 1L, 184L), dar.MN.L.type = structure(c(2L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
        "Median", "Plateau"), class = "factor"), dar.MN.L.Mo1_P1_A1 = c(NaN, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
        ), dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo1_P1_A1 = c(NaN, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), dar.MN.L.variability.....Mo1_P1_A1 = c(NaN, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
        )), .Names = c("dar.MN.L", "dar.MN.L.normalized", "dar.MN.L.variability....", 
    "dar.MN.L.count", "dar.MN.L.iso.count", "dar.MN.L.type", "dar.MN.L.Mo1_P1_A1", 
    "dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo1_P1_A1", "dar.MN.L.variability.....Mo1_P1_A1"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

I would like to have a separate data frame with only the header (row.names)

```
dar.MN.L
dar.MN.L.normalized
dar.MN.L.variability...
dar.MN.L.count
dar.MN.L.iso-count
dar.MN.L.type
dar.MN.L.Mo1_P1_A1
dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo1_P1_A1
dar.MN.L.variability... Mo1_P1_A1
```

Then from the data , I only want to keep all the columns that they have "dar.MN.L" and "dar.MN.L.normalized" and "dar.MN.L.Mo" and "dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo" 
An output of what I would like to have is below

```
output <- structure(list(dar.MN.L = c(0.6182, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.02381, 
0.070409, NaN, 0.092676, 0.21529, NaN, 0.072563), dar.MN.L.normalized = c(0.88095, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.034051, 0.079625, NaN, 0.1338, 0.28808, 
NaN, 0.10199), dar.MN.L.Mo1_P1_A1 = c(NaN, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo1_P1_A1 = c(NaN, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)), .Names = c("dar.MN.L", 
"dar.MN.L.normalized", "dar.MN.L.Mo1_P1_A1", "dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo1_P1_A1"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

what I do is as follows:

```
t <- colnames(df)
write.table (t,...)
```

Then I remove the columns I don't want manually and then

```
newdata <- df[t]
```

Comment: why you need new df with the colnames? also, all your cols in `df` contain "dar.MN.L"

Comment: @mtoto not all , it is a portion of my data. I need it to be saved in xls so that I can check the names manually too and see what I have

Comment: Why not `output <- dat[,grepl("logical_pattern_here",colnames(df))]`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - Please see how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Removing columns from a df is a very common question.  Search and research before posting

Comment: @Heroka what is dat in your command ?

Comment: @micstr I searched before I ask and I could not find anything similar. If you are aware of any, please post

Comment: Searching is hard when you don't know what to search for. What you want, is to select columns from a dataframe based on their names. So, you'll first need to find a way to get only the columns you need, and then you need to select columns. Converting them to another dataframe is unnecessary.

Comment: @Heroka it is. Actually I do it myself but it is still very time consuming because I must select each column that I need by hand. Look at above I modified the question

Comment: and why do you call "header(row.names)" they are just "column names"

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar  thanks for your comment, actually they are called with different names but I used it as a common one as you said. I don't know how to change the names to a more readable one. as I said above, it is small portion of my big data

Comment: @kiridahanet how do you know which columns to extract? do you have the patterns of the required column names in a variable? and why do you want to filter twice when your ultimate goal is to get only four columns?

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar at this moment I manually do it but the real data is over 10000 columns and not all are useful. what I want to keep are those columns that dar.MN.L, dar.MN.L.normalized, dar.MN.L.Mo and dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo. I don't care about what is written after .Mo but I keep them. I did not find any better option that is why I filter twice

Comment: this gives what you want `df[,c(match(c('dar.MN.L','dar.MN.L.normalized'), colnames(df)), unlist(lapply(c("dar.MN.L.Mo", "dar.MN.L.normalized.Mo"), function(x) grep(x, colnames(df)))))]` but the proper way to do this would be to store all the required columns with exact match and partial match in separate variables. I do not find those details in your question

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar please then make the proper way as an answer and if it gives me what I want, I will accept . you can also modify the question if you feel like it is not proper

Comment: @kiridahanet did you try it? are you getting what you want? try that in your original dataset and let me know

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar I tried it and it is very good , however, it changes the order of my columns for example dar.MN.L.Mo1, dar.MN.L.Mo10, dar.MN.L.Mo100 .... it does not follow the order as it was . however, for sure it works and select only those columns I need

Comment: use this to reorder `library(gtools);  df[,mixedorder(colnames(df))]`

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar that is cool, now I have what I need , thanks